# How to split a table *line* across multiple pages?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a table with a line containing a large text, and I would like to split the table line across multiple pages in the tex document, see the minimal working example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcount\my@repeat@count
\newcommand{\myrepeat}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \my@repeat@count=\z@
  \@whilenum\my@repeat@count<#1\do{#2\advance\my@repeat@count\@ne}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{longtable}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{.2\linewidth}|p{.8\linewidth}}
  Research Activity  & \myrepeat{400}{This is a very long text.}
\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can't with longtable. Why don't you use a description list instead?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: `\begin{description}\item[Research activity] long text ... \end{description}`. You can tweak the layout with the enumitem package.